# Multiple end receptacles in one room

Tags: receptacle

I have an old house and want to add an GFCI to the "first" outlet to add protection to the the outlet. However, one of the rooms has multiple end receptacles which means there are only one hot and one neutral wire coming in each box. How were these outlets wired?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to tell, could be a box in the ceiling with taps running down the walls. GFCI receptacles would be required at each location if you can't find a head end or use a breaker.

Comment: Can't really tell unless you open up every box in the circuit.  Wiring is supposed to be a tree topology, tee branches are OK.

Answer (score 1):

There is a junction box where the feed is split and goes to each of your "end" outlets if they are on the same circuit. If they are on different circuits, they could actually be end outlets for the two circuits.

What you'd have to do is install a separate GFCI outlet at each location. Check all the outlet boxes because you might find where the feed splits and you could install the GFCI outlet there.

Comment: These three outlets are on the same breaker.  I have looksed around the room but have no idea how o find the junction. Is there a tip to find this junction box?

Comment: There's no tip, just checking inside all the boxes for wires coming in and going out. It could be a switch box or in a light fixture box in the ceiling or attic.

Comment: Instead of replacing the outlets with GFCI (and buying 3 or 4 or 5), @vi1na2, purchase 1 GFCI _breaker_ and protect the whole circuit from that. It will be more expensive than 1 GFCI outlet, but less expensive than multiple outlets.

Comment: Will try your advice, JACK.Thanks!

Comment: I agree. Will go this route if I can't find the junction box. Thanks, FreeMan.

Answer (score 0):

Older homes are regularly wired in a spider format as the wiring is punched up from underneath or down from the attic.
This is different than normal daisy chain used in new construction.  There is no right or wrong method as long as the splices are in boxes,  Proper wire size and type for the job.

The layout is usually whatever is easiest, so it is quite common to have multiple end receptacles per room if not all of them in an older home that has had wiring updates.

For homes with multiple taps from a single feeder,  GFCI breakers are less expensive as only one will be needed for the entire circuit.  Where a single room may have 4-6 and there may be multiple rooms on each circuit.

Comment: I experienced the wiring go from one room to the other room. However, it is easy to find the very first outlet and then put a GFCI there. This room is entirely different. As JACK suggested, there may be a junction box where the wiring is splitted to these three end outlet as what you call a spider format? Same question as for JACK, is there a way to find the junction box?

Comment: Yes spiders are branch circuits that have a a run to a location then split 3/4 times and possibly run to a second box and split 3-4 times. This is why I said sometimes it is cheaper to put a GFCI breaker in than try to put individual GFCI’s as the only common point is the breaker. I have seen DIY do 6+ from a single location I put 3-4 in and run to a second box and that uses less wire and less back and forth.

Comment: I agree. Will go this route if I can't find the junction box. Thanks, Ed Beal..